# Android SIP library VS pjsip: which one?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I intend to write an SIP client for Android (and maybe other systems but let's make Android first) and I was wondering which library would be the best to use: the one we got on the android sdk or pjsip? And why?

Has anyone got some feedback with pjsip?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, PJSIP is the best one. It is free and open source multimedia communication library. It is designed to be very small in footprint, have high performance, and very flexible.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, however I decided to use the android package

Comment: Finally I'll have to use pjsip, the android package doesn't handle crypted channels.